# How do you use the jQuery UI Datepicker with MVC's Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using Model binding with the Entity Framework and have an Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.date) input. I know how to tell jQuery how to implement a datepicker but not in this context. What would I need to add here to have a calendar popup when the user enters this field?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll want to use the HtmlHelper overload that allows you to specify Html attributes. Then target them with the jquery selector.

```
// in view
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, new { @class="datepicker" })%>

// in js
$(document).ready({
         $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
```

Though I recommend using `EditorFor` instead.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)%>
```

You can create an EditorTemplate to handle any field that is a `DateTime` and have it output the proper field.

Create `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx` and put this in it...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>    
<%= Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), new { @class="datepicker" } )%>
```

Or if you need to allow DateTime's with nulls:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>    
<%= Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue? Model.Value.ToShortDateString():""), new { @class="datepicker"} )%>
```

Then you can always use EditorFor and have a central ascx to edit if you ever want to modify the way date times are handled in your views.

Comment: +1: however the `DateTime.ascx` and EditorFor didn't work for me. I just create add the ascx control `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx' with the code you have right? what about the `Model.ToShort..` do I update that? where does the script go in?

Comment: How do you include `<%= Html.TextBox` in `ascx` file? I have `Html` undefined error

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code sample (TextBoxFor) you are using MVC2....

Here's an example [using MVC 2](http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/13/using-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-with-asp-net-mvc-2-templates/) that creates a template that will call the jQery date picker whenever you use a date & a second more [in depth example](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/).

Comment: The second link in your answer is amazing. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad you liked it.  .Net MVC definitely has a lot of good nuggets in it!

Answer (score 1):

Create an EditorTemplate for the DateTime type and then use EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor.  The edit template should be a user control called DateTime.ascx with code something like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", Model))%>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#<%: ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName %>").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
              showButtonPanel: true,
              gotoCurrent: true
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Check out Scott Hanselman's talk on MVC 2 on channel 9.
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman/

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an approach similar to Marc's. Here's my own version of it:

" %>

```
<%string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;%>
<%string id = name.Replace(".", "_");%>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "date" }) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)%>
</div>      

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#<%=id%>").datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'button', 
            buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.gif") %>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

create your EditorTemplates folder under the shared folder and name it DateTime.ascx.