# jQuery DatePicker MVC4 EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker, editorfor

I need to use datepicker on an EditorFor field.

My code for the view is:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("birthDate","birthDate")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.birthDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.birthDate)
</div>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: "-99Y",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    });
```

I can't make it work. I have the following error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method 'datepicker'.

I have already loaded jQuery before I try to call the function.

Comment: verify the order of the jquery, could you post the whole view file including the scripts?

Comment: Can you put how you solve it?

Comment: I checked the order that I was loading jquery. And then I changed EditorFor for TextBoxFor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.birthDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

Will not work, because **"EditorFor" will not accept** (pass along to the DOM) **a Class**.

So, you **need to use "TextBoxFor"** which will accept a Class or **better yet, create an EditorTemplate** to handle any field that is a DateTime and add the class there. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924660/3338231) details how to make the Template.

Once you have the Class working (can be verified in the source code), the rest is just referencing the jquery code. I use

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

and activating it with the script you already have. Watch that the name '.datepicker' is Exactly the same as the Class.

Answer (score 4):

EditorFor  accept  a  class for me

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker",@Name="birthday",@PlaceHolder = "mm/dd/yyyy" } })
```

Html  markup

```
class="datepicker text-box single-line"
```

The Class is  work.

Comment: Great answer :D, it's better than the chosen one!

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar issue, solved by using the HTML5 functionality, that has support for datetime, in your example I would suggest trying somthing like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("birthDate","birthDate")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.birthDate, new { @class = "datepicker", type="datetime-local"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.birthDate)
</div>
```

the only thing that I addes is a type ="datetime-local"