# How can I put a datepicker with mvc5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            @Html.Label("Data de Agendamento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="datepicker">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And at the end of my view, I have:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
}
```

How can I do to put a Datepicker(jquery or other) on my textbox(razor)?
Debugging the page on dev tools of chrome, I have this error:

> GET http://localhost:55839/bundles/jquery-ui 404 (Not Found)

I do not know how to do.

Comment: Did you add the bundle in the RegisterBundles function?

Comment: No, how can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427153/jquery-datepicker-mvc4-editorfor

Comment: Add jquery ui bundle to RegisterBundles method follow steps mention in here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification or if you don't want to minify just add jquery ui js reference to page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For up to date browsers, the best choice is adding these data attributes to related property in class difination:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Then just use  @Html.EditorFor for property in view.

For bundles error check your bundles/jquery-ui  in **App_Start > BundleConfig.cs** . probably definition has errore

Comment: Hardly the best since `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome. It will just render a standard textbox in FireFox or IE.

Comment: [Refer IE support for HTML5 inputs](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-9/ie-10/ie-11.html)

Comment: I just tested this in the most recent versions of (as of today) Chrome, IE, Edge, FireFox and Opera and this worked like a champ.